# Opening a Silverlight 5 OOB app from a browser - Passing Data

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-oob

We have a Silverlight 5 XAP file we host in an ASP.NET site.  This SL code notes it is running in-browser and ultimately prompts the user to install locally with extended permissions.  This part is very straightforward and works fine.  The purpose for needing to install SL XAP locally is that the OOB instance has easier access to elevated permissions we require to execute some local printing applications.

Our issue is the second time a user of the ASP.NET site (a 3rd party document management portal we are integrating with via custom ASCX controls) navigates to our specific "printing" functionality (which we are doing via the SL 5 OOB app).  We'd like them to launch the already installed SL 5 XAP file and have some way of passing data into the OOB app.

Once a XAP is installed locally, is there a way to "launch" this instance of it from a browser again?  (as opposed to a user going to their start bar or desktop and clicking the created link?)   If this is possible, and we can re-launch it, how might data be passed into it?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated?

-Kevin Grossnicklaus
kvgros@architectnow.net

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch Silverlight Out-of-Browser from browser post-installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325647/launch-silverlight-out-of-browser-from-browser-post-installation)

Comment: This question has been asked many times (the answer is no), this has not changed with Silverlight 5.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978910/open-silverlight-oob-on-url-if-installed, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958866/is-it-possible-to-launch-a-silverlight-4-oob-application-from-a-web-page